# FatalThrowableError Call to undefined method App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated() laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, middleware

I'm having the problem that when my user is not logged in and I go to a route that needs authentication for my blog, it throws the exception: "

> Call to undefined method App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated()

"
Although I don't have a method named  `unauthenticated()` in the directory

> App\Exceptions\Handler.

I want to show login form for my user when he/she click on a route that needs authentication, how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App\Exceptions\Handler file, add a function unauthenticated, Laravel will recognise this and will execute what you defined here.

You can add this function:

```
public function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return ''; // use redirect('/login') or something if you want to redirect to login.
    }
```

Although if you use php artisan make:auth, Laravel sets the unauthenticated page automatically to the login page. So don't know if you used this, maybe you changed something else in the standard Laravel code.

I hope the above function helps.

Comment: This is not the way to fix this problem, see the https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication read Redirecting Unauthenticated Users!

Comment: It is a way to fix the problem, but the comment above is maybe a better solution, forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

The unauthenticated exception thrown by the framework itself.

If you have the auth middleware on the route, it should redirect you to the login page `Route::get('/test', 'TestController@show')->middleware('auth');`

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) for more info.

Comment: I'm using following middleware for  PostController :                        `    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }`       I'm locking down the posts from logged out users ,but when they try to click on **posts** to edit/delete  posts,they face this porblem,I want to show login form to them so that after authentication they can edit/delete posts,how to do this ?

Comment: Add the middleware only to the edit/delete posts, so you protect those and leave the index endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because unauthenticated function somehow missing from error handler.

Go to **App\Exceptions\Handler.php** file and add the following function.

```
<?php        
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
```

change `guest('login')` to your desired location.

You can use it in class like this:

```
Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException as AuthenticationException;
```